# $\int_0^\infty f(t)^2 x(t)^2 dt \le \int^1_0 f(t)^2 dt?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, functions, hilbert-spaces

Let $f$ let a bounded decreasing positive function on $(0,\infty)$, and  $x$ be a positive function such that $x(t)\le 1$ for every $t\in (0,\infty)$ and $\int_0^\infty (x(t))^{2}dt\le 1$. Show (or disprove) that
$$ \int_0^\infty f(t)^2 x(t)^2 dt \le \int^1_0 f(t)^2 dt.$$

Comment: You can improve your question by providing contexts and your thoughts. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write $g(t) = f(t)^2$ and $y(t) = x(t)^2$ and notice that

- $g$ is bounded decreasing non-negative on $(0, \infty)$.
- $y$ is non-negative, bounded above by $1$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty} y(t) \, dt \leq 1$.

So we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty} g(t)y(t) \, dt
&\leq g(1) \int_{1}^{\infty} y(t) \, dt \\
&\leq g(1) \left(1 - \int_{0}^{1} y(t) \, dt \right) \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} g(1) (1 - y(t)) \, dt \\
&\leq \int_{0}^{1} g(t) (1 - y(t)) \, dt.
\end{align*}

Rearranging, we obtain

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} g(t)y(t) \, dt \leq \int_{0}^{1} g(t) \, dt $$

which is equivalent to the inequality in question.

Comment: Beautiful proof! THX!